# Validar tipo de dato con dataannotations y Jquey validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-validate, dataannotations

Actualmente trabajo con un proyecto de NetCore y estoy comenzando a hacer las validaciones con jquery validate unobtrusive sucede que  las validaciones funcionan de manera correcta pero tengo un problema con los campos numéricos ya que les he aplicado una mascara de forma que en mi formulario el valor de campo se muestra de la siguiente forma:
Valor:  $1,000,000.00

La validación dice que el campo valor debe ser un número, mi conclusión es que al ser "valor" un campo de tipo decimal no puede parsear  el valor con la mascara debido al signo de pesos y las comas, el problema es que logro hacer que el controller reconozca el formato o quitarle el formato antes de que se envíe.

Este es mi código

```
<label for="numValue" asp-for="Value"></label>
<input asp-for="Value" type="text" id="numValue" class="form-control input-numeric" data-allowzero="none" disabled="disabled" data-thousands="," data-decimal="." data-precision="2" data-prefix="$" />
<span asp-validation-for="Value"></span>

public class Transaction
{
    [Display(Name ="Monto")]              
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un monto.")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Intente  hacerlo con JS, antes de enviar el formulario quitarle  el formato pero no funciona por alguna razón unobtrusive se envia antes de que le de click al boton de submit

```
$("#frmAddTransaction").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#frmAddTransaction").validate({
       submitHandler: function(form) {   
       $("#numValue").val($("#numValue").val().replace("$","").split(',').join(""));
       $(form).submit();
    }
    });
)}
```

De antemano muchas  gracias por sus comentarios, este es el plugin con el que coloca la mascara https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ya se ha comentado antes mira el problema es Jquery o javascript que no soportan el formato europeo yo lo solucione haciendo que los campos de mis modelos fueran string y luego en el mapper los convierto a decimal.

Es mas trabajo porque debes de hacer las validaciones manuales.

En mi entidad por ejemplos tienes

public decimal monto {get; set;}

bueno en el modelo

public string monto {get; set;}

ya sea en jquery debes de hacer las validaciones para evitar te manden texto o caracteres raros.

Comment: Gracias  por el dato, no me convence del  todo hacerlo de esa manera no se me hace "limpio"  pero  funciona por  ahora

Comment: Si te doy la razón a pesar que lo solucione de esa forma segui leyendo y encontré una forma mas elegante, voy a publicarlo pero ahora estoy muy liado, talvez mañana lo haga cuando lo tenga te comparto el link.

Comment: aqui mi otra solucion espero sea mejor saludos   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372027/separador-de-miles-decimales-asp-core-3-x-y-jquery/372028#372028