# ¿separador de miles, decimales asp core 3.x y jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Este es un problema que viene hablándose desde hace mucho rato y al menos los que venimos trabajando desde el 2010 con asp mvc hemos tenido.

Y ahora en ASP Core 3.x no ha sido la diferencia, ahora que estoy desarrollando una aplicación web desde cero me encontré con este viejo enemigo.

Y cuál es el problema bueno no importa si estas usando regional americano coma(,) para miles y punto(.) para decimales o europeo punto(.) para miles y coma(,) para decimales siempre jquery dispara el error al validar el campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error no es de asp core en realidad es de jquery que siempre espera que el número sea 2500.25 si con punto decimal americano lo que hace que para los que trabajamos con aplicaciones que se usan tanto en América como en España sea un problemón.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo corregí haciendo que los decimales en mi model fueran string y luego lo convertía a decimal en la entidad, pero lo que, aunque despreciable este tipo de conversión y validación quita tiempo y ralentiza tu aplicación.

Pero quise aprovechar una característica de ASP Core donde puedes manipular el model y pienso que es una solución mucho más natural al estilo de un MVP(Most Valuable Professional) :D, aunque no lo soy pero lo intento.

en mi modelo tengo algo así:

```
      [DataType(DataType.Currency), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
      [Required, Display(Name = "Neto", Description = "Neto de la factura", Prompt = "Neto de la factura")]
      public Decimal neto { get; set; }
```

1. Primero quito la validación para todos los campos decimales para la vista de esa forma jquery no me envia el error en cuestion y lo hago así por input:

   `<script type="text/javascript"> $("#neto").removeAttr("data-val"); </script>`
2. Con jquery manipulo el input para que me ponga separador de miles y de decimales, no lo publico porque en la web hay muchos metodos y seguro mejores que los mios.
3. Voy a bindear el type decimal y para eso creare un par de clases dentro de una carpeta Binder, que puede tener cualquier nombre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. creamos la primera clase que es la enlace con una interfaz de propia de ASP para hacer el binder de esta forma puedes copiarla integra.

Código:

```
public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
     public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
     {
          if (context == null)
          {
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
          }

          if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(decimal))
          {
               return new DecimalModelBinder();
          }

          return null;
     }
}
```

Si os fijaís trabajamos con la interface IModelBinderProvider y le indicamos que cuando en el modelo sea cual sea llegue a una tyoe Decimal implemente la clase   DecimalModelBinder()

Que tambien se las dejo aquí con comentarios:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
     public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
          var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

          //Primero obtenemos el separador de miles para procesar la información aqui no nos interesa
          //el separador decimal porque a este es ya core y eso lo maneja perfecto el framework
          var separadormiles = valueProviderResult.Culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator;

          //Si es nulo pues finaliza la clase sin hacer más
          if (valueProviderResult == null)
          {
               return Task.CompletedTask;
          }

          //obtenmos el valor del modelo 
          string value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

          //si no hay valor finaliza si hacer nada
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
          {
               return Task.CompletedTask;
          }

          // Removemos comas o puntos (separador de miles) nada mas
          // los decimales no importa si es separado por coma o punto 
          // dependiendo la region ya que eso lo manipula bien core
          value = value.Replace(separadormiles, string.Empty).Trim();

          decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value);

          //retornamos el valor que si se manipula perfectamente en el controller
          //mapping o clase
          bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(myValue);
          return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
}
```

5. Solo hace falta una ultima cosa es hacer la inyección en el Startup.cs en la seccion de "ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)"
   agregamos lo siguente:

   ```
           #region Binder

           services.AddControllers(options =>
           {
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
           });

           #endregion
   ```

Y bueno ya esta asi podemos manipular el model de una forma elegante en ASP Core 3.x
cualquier duda me la comentan

Comment: ya lo he corregido gracias

Comment: en 24 horas recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada :D le ayudarás al sitio a mantener la buena salud por efecto de % de preguntas resueltas

Comment: Vale gracias por recordar